# How to plot the decision boundary line which same with the decision boundary of plt.contourf?

Tags: python, matplotlib

From [this](https://www.llipe.com/2017/04/19/programando-un-clasificador-perceptron-en-python/) link:

[image]
As shown in function `plot_decision_regions`, the decision regions can be visualized by dense sampling via meshgrid. However, if the grid resolution is not enough, as artificially set below, the boundary will appear inaccurate.

Implement function `plot_decision_boundary` below to analytically compute and plot the decision boundary.

Therefore, I would like to ask how can I change the function of `plot_decision_boundary` to display the line which is same with the decision boundary of `plt.contourf()`. (like the green line)

[image]

```py
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

def plot_decision_regions(X, y, classifier, resolution=0.01):
    markers = ('s', 'x', 'o', '^', 'v')
    colors = ('red', 'blue', 'lightgreen', 'gray', 'cyan')
    cmap = ListedColormap(colors[:len(np.unique(y))])
    x1_min, x1_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    x2_min, x2_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, resolution),
                           np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, resolution))
    Z = classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)
    Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)
    plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z, alpha=0.3, cmap=cmap)
    plt.xlim(xx1.min(), xx1.max())
    plt.ylim(xx2.min(), xx2.max())
    for idx, cl in enumerate(np.unique(y)):
        plt.scatter(x=X[y == cl, 0], 
                    y=X[y == cl, 1],
                    alpha=0.8, 
                    c=colors[idx],
                    marker=markers[idx], 
                    label=cl, 
                    edgecolor='black')

def plot_decision_boundary(X, y, classifier):       
    # replace the two lines below with your code
    x1_interval = [X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1]
    x2_interval = [X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1]

    plt.plot(x1_interval, x2_interval, color='green', linewidth=4, label='boundary')

low_res = 0.1 # intentional for this exercise
plot_decision_regions(X, y, classifier=ppn, resolution=low_res)
plot_decision_boundary(X, y, classifier=ppn)
plt.xlabel('sepal length [cm]')
plt.ylabel('petal length [cm]')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: A filled contour is produced with `plt.contourf`. A contour line is produced with `plt.contour`.

Comment: I would like to understand how do the plt.contour produce the boundary line. (calculation). I want to add the line by myself (like def plot_decision_boundary).

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The algorithm is found in [_contour.cpp](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/src/_contour.cpp) and the way it's called can be found in [contour.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/contour.py).

Comment: It is solved. I referenced ''' https://medium.com/@thomascountz/calculate-the-decision-boundary-of-a-single-perceptron-visualizing-linear-separability-c4d77099ef38 ''' to understand how to plot the decision boundary line.

Answer (score 0):

it must be hku comp7404 HW.
you need to determine two points(-b / w1,0) and (0, -b / w2).